# converting binary, decimal, hexa etc. what is the role of bit?

Tags: binary, hex, decimal, converters

If I have got 1101 0010 0010 0010 on a 16bit system and want to convert it to decimal the result is -11,742 (teacher told me)

But if I enter the binary number into my calculator I get 53794.

Why is this the case? How does the system (8bit, 16bit, 32bit, 64bit) affect this?

I tried to convert the binary number with hand (2+32+512+4096+16384+32768 = 53794) but only to confirm my calculator....

Comment: I think you mean to integer (signed), not decimal. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because computer arhitmetic is based on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

You shoud read about [method of colpement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements)

For example in complement decimal number natural subtraction looks like that (using 4 digits):

```
0000
0001 -
9999 =
```

It's obviously -1 because in complemental system first digit (in big endian of course, you shoud be familiar with [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)) defines sign. For example in decimal complement 4 is 4, 4 is 4, 3 is 3, 2 is 2, 1 is 1, 0 is 0, 9 is -1, 8 is -2, 7 is -3, 6 is -4 and 5 is -5.

It's because in complement number system you always operate on same number of digits but you are adding and substracting as always except ignoring overflowing result. For example with two decimal digits:

```
      04
      05 -
 ...9999 =
```

As I told result are only two digits (we added two digits) so the result is 99. As I also mentioned before first number is interpreted as -1 (not 9). Because it is positional number system we can easy convert this result to our normal decimal system just summing digits multypling by correct power's of ten:

```
10^1 * 9 + 10^0 * 9
//as I told - first nine is -1 so:
10^1 * -1 + 10^0*9 = -10 + 9 = -1
```

Now try with first result:

```
9999 = 9 * 10^3 + 10^2 * 9 + 10^1 * 9 + 10^0 * 9
//first nine is -1 so:
-1 * 10^3 + 999 = -1000 + 999 = -1
```

Now in binary it is much simpler because first number just tells as what sign is. Try with 8 bit number:

1111 1111

It's obviously -1 because if we add 1 the result will be 0. You may say I'm laying becaus you can simply make following addition:

```
  1111 1111
  0000 0001 +
1 0000 0000 =
```

But it's not correct in complement system. It's because in complement system first digit not only describe sign of number but also all number can be infinitly expanded by that digit! It's why id complement decimal 99 = 9999 ! It also means that we can easy expand 8 bytes number to for example 32 bytes!

For example try with numbers 17 and -1. You are now familiar with -1. In 8 bytes two's complemex -1 is:

1111 1111

Expanded to 32 bytes it gives us:

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111

To convert it to normal decimal system we need to do 2^31 + 2^30 + ... + 2^0 but (as I mentioned) first 1 is -1 so it's exactly -1 * 2^31 + 2^30 + .. + 2^0 if you compute this it's exactly -2147483648 + 2147483647 = -1 !

0001 0001 (decimal 17)

Expanded to 32 bites gives:

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0001

And we can agree it's still 17 :)

To provide I'm not some crazy, just IT student I'm going to present C++ code that does exactly that stuff:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    char eightBits = 255; //eightBits := 0x11111111
    int eightBytes = eightBits; //eightBytes becaming 255, right?
    cout <<eightBytes <<endl; // MAGIC ! 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it depends on how much space there is. The most significant bit is used to determine whether or not the number is negative.

In a 32-bit system, the two following numbers are equivalent:

```
1101 0010 0010 0010
0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 0010 0010 0010
```

As a signed 16-bit value, the 1 at the beginning denotes that it's a negative number. To get its value, flip each bit, then add one.

```
1101 0010 0010 0010
0010 1101 1101 1101
0010 1101 1101 1110
= 11742
```

As an *unsigned* 16-bit value, all sixteen bits are used to determine the magnitude. This would result in 53794.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 0):

The unpoken bit here is about the sign. It is stored on the front end and denotes the sign.

http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_short.html?decimal=045049049055052050

More succinctly, a 16bit 'word' or integer is usually called a 'short' on most systems and represents signed number between −32,768 and +32,767. This is the 'binary' number to which your teacher is referring, which is not stored directly as a binary number, but in binary format. There are actually only 15 spots to store the value and one that must be reserved for the sign. Otherwise, an unsigned value can use all 16 spots for numbers and thus can go to from 0 to +65,535.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to represent binary numbers:

- Unsigned (what you are doing)
- Signed
- 1's complement
- 2's complement (what you are supposed to do according to your teacher)

Digital systems generally use 2's complement representation.

To get decimal number for a binary number in 2's complement:
1. First bit is the sign bit. If the number starts with 0, it is positive, otherwise it is negative.
2. If the number is positive, its decimal value is unsigned value of the remaining bits other than the sign bit. If the number is negative, its absolute decimal value = (signed value of the complement of the remaining bits)+1.

Answer (score 0):

In computers, it is common to represent "two's complement" signed numbers by assuming that the leftmost bit is duplicated an infinite number of times, so that the bit sequence (1101 0010 0010 0010) is regarded as (1111....1111 1101 0010 0010 0010).  Although an infinite string of ones may seem like an infinitely large number, adding one to such a string will yield an infinite string of zeroes (i.e. 0).  Thus, an infinite string of ones is the additive inverse of 1, and thus has an effective value of -1.  An infinite string of ones followed by some number of zeroes, will be the additive inverse of a single 1 followed by that number of zeroes (so in your example, the leftmost "1" has an effective value of -32768 rather than +32768).  While the fact that applying the power-series formula to 1+2+4+8+16+32+64... yields -1 is often regarded as an anomaly, it is consistent with the way that "two's complement" math works.

Note that while many descriptions of two's complement math simply describe the sign of the uppermost bit's "scaling factor" as being inverted (e.g. -32768 rather than +32768), thinking in terms of left-padding with copies of the leftmost bit makes it easier to understand why signed numbers behave as though the leftmost number is duplicated (e.g. converting a negative 16-bit integer to a 32-bit integer fills the leftmost 16 bits with ones).